# Thymeleaf fragment not being resolved

Tags: thymeleaf

I made sure there is th:fragment and the name is called correctly in the main html. However, it is still not being resolved

In main html

```
<div th:replace="fragments/navbar :: navbar"></div>
```

Fragment

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Chrono Airlines</a>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

EDIT: Changing the directory helped

Comment: To provide any help, we would need more information. I would expect to see how you are using `th:fragment`, and how you are invoking the fragment (e.g. with `th:insert` or `th:replace` and so on). Where is the fragment file stored, relative to the main HTML file? (Minor note: The HTML in your question has fewer opening DIVs than it has closing DIVs. I assume that's just a copy/paste thing.)

Comment: My bad I missed that

Comment: @andrewjames I address it. Yeah the /div at the end is not necessary. Was testing stuff

Comment: OK - thank you for the updates. If you don't want to use `th:fragment`, then your reference has to be a valid CSS selector. So try this: `th:replace="fragments/navbar :: div.navbar"`. If that doesn't work (I've never tried this with a class selector) then use an ID selector. So, add an ID to the div: `<div id="my_div_id" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">`, and then use that as the selector: `th:replace="fragments/navbar :: #my_div_id"`.

Comment: Related documentation is [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#referencing-fragments-without-thfragment).

Comment: @andrewjames I'm still getting the same error. Should I share more of my code?org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [fragments/navbar], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (template: "flights-listOneWay" - line 12, col 6)

Comment: I assume the navbar is in a file called `navbar.html`, which is in a directory called `fragments`, which is in your `resources` directory. And your `main.html` file is also in `resources`. Are you using Spring or just Thymeleaf on its own? Can you edit your question to show (a) the latest code you are using, and (b) where the templates are stored?